# Why does HP Envy 700 freeze and glitch out?

Tags: windows-10, hp-envy

[image]

I have an HP Envy 700 PC Series. I was out of town for about five days (the computer ran while I was absent) and when I got back, the computer wouldn't respond (it was on and sleeping when I tried). After restarting it, the issue started (as seen in the picture above). My guess is the hard drive's failing, which I base off the following:

- I tried hooking the tower up to a different monitor, but the same issue persists.
- My friend suggested the graphics card is failing, but the entire system still freezes.
- The system initially shows the screen above when booted and stops there, indicating the hard drive may not be readable?

To clarify, the system appears to both freeze AND glitch at the same time. This much is certain as the loading screen never progresses.

Notes of interest:

- I managed to load the system entirely just once after a few attempts and even login. I could not see anything on my actual desktop and the WIFI icon was absent in the task bar; everything else seemed functional. The system crashed, however, after opening an application. Now, the system freezes almost as soon as the HP logo appears on subsequent restarts.
- During my initial restarts, I saw a message below the HP loading animation that said "Diagnosing your PC..." This message disappeared in subsequent restarts.
- I don't believe I have a virus because I had at least two antivirus applications running prior to this incident.
  -I've had this computer since late 2014; it seems odd the parts are already failing when older models lasted WAY longer (and still run!).

My biggest concern at this point is ensuring I can recover my data with an enclosure kit and reinstall Windows 10 on another hard drive if necessary.

So, few questions...

A. What's happening  (i.e., what part is failing)?
B. Is my data recoverable?
C. Can I fix the part or will I need to replace it?

Comment: Sometimes two AV products can actually cause problems. If you have maybe one anti-malware software, and another AV that scans/checks realtime, and then maybe another AV that only does scheduled scans it'd be fine as long as you add exceptions in each for the other but I've seen more than one AV ont he same OS cause strange problems in the past. Try to see if it can boot to the recovery console, etc. and run a check disk. Boot to a Linux live OS on CD or USB and see if it sees the HD, can mount to it, browse files to copy to another drive, etc.

Comment: If you can get it to boot, try admin elevated `SFC SCANNOW` but I'd start with `chkdsk` to find and potentially fix issues it may find with the file system assuming the drive is readable and not hosed up, etc.

Comment: could be GPU memory failing